# Peel and stick vinyl on existing tile - how to best level the tile floor for installation?

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring, ceramic-tile, self-leveling-concrete, leveling

I knew installing peel and stick vinyl planks on uneven surfaces was a bad idea, but I decided to go ahead anyway (big mistake). It looks a lot worse than I originally expected, as the bulge is very noticeable:

[image]

Before it gets any worse, I want like to level the rest of the tile floor before continuing. How do I best fill the grout joints as well as the elevation difference among the tiles themselves? What levelling compound should I use? This is peel and stick vinyl so the substance needs to work well with the adhesive on the planks. Here's an example of the joints I need filled:

[image]

And lastly, is there any way I can remedy or at least hide the occasional bulges in existing planks? Only some random bulges here and there, most of the surface is still fairly even. I'm thinking of using adhesive film like this d-c-fix [roll](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07Q8NFWTM/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1) but not sure if it will last with foot traffic.

Comment: Fix the bulges: Pull up the new flooring. Level the _whole_ floor. Relay the floor.